# Absolute Value of Cosine and Sine in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, intuition

Is it generally true that $|\cos(z)|\leq1$, $|\sin(z)|\leq1$ $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$? I think I'm missing something here (I think it does not hold, only if $z \in \mathbb{R}$). If this were not the case, then could someone give me a concrete example of this?

Thanks for the help, this question has been troubling my mind for a while.

Comment: By Liouville's theorem, bounded entire functions are constant. If what you ask was true, $\sin$ and $\cos$ would be bounded entire functions and thus constant, which is absurd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $z = it, t\in\Bbb R$. $\lim_{t\to\infty}\sin(it)=\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

No, $\cos$ and $\sin$ are surjective functions. We have $\cos(\mathbb C)=\sin(\mathbb C)=\mathbb C$. If you have a holomorphic function on $\mathbb C$ which is not constant then it is almost surjective meaning that you have $f(\mathbb C)=A$ where $A=\mathbb C$ or $A=\mathbb C\setminus\{a\}$ for one $a\in\mathbb C$.